# Case-style project management software

Tags: process, tracking

I am looking at a slightly different take on project management - rather than having a set project performed over a particular timeline, I am looking at individual investigative cases as being their own projects.

Research misconduct accusations are where someone, usually a researcher, is accused of having done something wrong.

When an accusation is received by the office, it follows a stepwise process of investigation, which is a process we have mapped out. It could almost be viewed as a type of flowchart with a lot of branches, and information recorded at each step.

Over the last few years, this process has been done in a fairly ad hoc manner by people, however we would like to introduce a more systematic process so that we can record what steps have been taken, see what the next steps are, and create metrics based around this. We need to be able to attach files specifically for each step (e.g. memos, evidence, emails).

I have looked at a few types of project management software, but they all focus on linear processes, rather than branching processes, and also on specific due dates for each step to finish, which is something that we don't want (each cases' timeline is different).
I have also looked at some case management systems, mostly for law, but these seem to lack the more process-centric side which is what we are really after, they seem to be more about having a list of cases and then a bit where you can record case notes for each.

Does anyone have suggestions as to options we can explore to create this system?

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic here. Please, take a look at [this page](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to learn more about on-topic questions. Also, you can try to ask your question at [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're referring to is more suited to a Workflow Management System. These are usually referred to as **Workflow Management Tools** or **Business Process Management Tools**.

A quick example (not by any means recommending this product, just an example): http://www.processmaker.com/

Project Management tools are great for managing projects, but not much else.